# Multiple Ajax run syncronus in .each loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to run AJAX requests for multiple time to get data from different folders and at the last one more AJAX will fire to make a zip of the data.
every thing is done but the biggest issue is some files runs after the file file run so they can't be include in zip file.
Please suggest what to do?

```
$('#View_Rep').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#restable').hide();
    document.adminweeklycorrection.action = '';
    $('#centerSec').css('display', 'none');
    $('#processingDiv').css('display', 'block');
    $('#processingDiv').html("<img height='150' src='img/loading-circle.gif'><h4>Processing data</h4>");
    var carr = $('#wkarr').val();
    carr = carr.split(",");
    $.each(carr, function(n) {
        if ($('#weekarray').val()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "rxml.php",
                method: "POST",
                async: "false",
                data: $("#adminweeklycorrection").serialize()
            }).done(function(msg) {
                if (n == parseFloat(carr.length) - parseFloat(1)) {
                    $('#processingDiv').html("<img height='150' src='img/loading-circle.gif'><h4>Preparing reports</h4>");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "cmbrxml.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        async: "false",
                        data: $("#adminweeklycorrection").serialize()
                    }).done(function(msg) {
                        $('#processingDiv').html("<h3>Report generated successfully</h3><h4><a href='" + msg + "'>Download Report</a></h4><h5><a href='adminchartcorrection.php'>Back</a></h5>");
                        if ($('#logtype').val() == 'Ship') {
                            $('#processingDiv').append("<form name='send_mail' id='send_mail' method='post' action='adminchartcorrection.php'><input type='hidden' name='chartnumber' id='chartnumber' value='" + $('#chartnumber').val() + "'><input type='submit' name='send_mail' value='Send Mail' id='send_mail'></form>");
                        }
                        //redir(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
            var curr = $('#weekarray').val();
            curr = curr.split(",");
            var sftd = curr.shift();
            //$('#weekarray').val('');
            $('#weekarray').val(curr);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Bad coding habit...Not a good idea to loop Ajax

Comment: but I have to run multiple requests then what is the other right way?

Comment: I just want to run all the files and when all files are executed then run another file to create a zip of the collected data.but some times some of the files runs after the zip request file so they are not including

Comment: Loop Each then Save your data in javascript array then Only onc POST call  to your ajax page passing javascript array. In return from PHP script loop that array and save result in anoth php array. Finally Just Send one JSON encoded array containg all your data. Loop ajax response on Success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if loop index is the last one does not mean that related ajax request was the last one executed. Instead of that, make a variable with requests count and decrease it on every requests' done method.

Try this:

```
var ajaxRequestsLeft = carr.length;        //added
$.each(carr, function(n) {
    if ($('#weekarray').val()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "rxml.php",
            method: "POST",
            async: "false",
            data: $("#adminweeklycorrection").serialize()
        }).done(function(msg) {
            ajaxRequestsLeft--;            //added
            if(ajaxRequestsLeft == 0) {    //modified
                $('#processingDiv').html("<img height='150' src='img/loading-circle.gif'><h4>Preparing reports</h4>");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "cmbrxml.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    async: "false",
                    data: $("#adminweeklycorrection").serialize()
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    $('#processingDiv').html("<h3>Report generated successfully</h3><h4><a href='" + msg + "'>Download Report</a></h4><h5><a href='adminchartcorrection.php'>Back</a></h5>");
                    if ($('#logtype').val() == 'Ship') {
                        $('#processingDiv').append("<form name='send_mail' id='send_mail' method='post' action='adminchartcorrection.php'><input type='hidden' name='chartnumber' id='chartnumber' value='" + $('#chartnumber').val() + "'><input type='submit' name='send_mail' value='Send Mail' id='send_mail'></form>");
                    }
                    //redir(msg);
                });
            }
        });
var curr = $('#weekarray').val();
curr = curr.split(",");
var sftd = curr.shift();
        //$('#weekarray').val('');
        $('#weekarray').val(curr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to make Async requests (they will fire at same time and will not have to wait until previous one finished).

And use promises. (I'm not familiar with jquery promises so will give abstract example):

```
var promises = [];
$.each(arr....
    // as I said I'm not sure if $.ajax returns promise in jquery (I use angular). This is just abstract example
    var promise = $.ajax(.... async: TRUE ....)
    promises.push(promise);
});

// again, this is just abstract example, but promises library that you'll use will have a way to register a callback when array of promises are finished
$q.all(promises).then(function(responses) {
    // now ALL requests are finished and you have ALL responses in "responses array
});
```